# ImageMagick - How to detect orientation of bank cheques and change orienation programmatically

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract, imagemagick-convert

I have lots of images of the bank cheques, many of them are in portrait mode and many are in landscape mode.

How can I auto-detect the orientation and change the orientation of all images to landscape mode so that they return proper output for Tesseract OCR.

[Bank cheque image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmNNe.jpg)

I want to change it so that it looks like this.

[After processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ya2U.jpg)

Comment: You could try passing it to Tesseract both ways and see which way works.

Answer (score 0):

Many digital cameras today include an orientation field in the meta data.  If that is true, then you can use Imagemagick's -auto-orient function. That is:

```
convert -auto-orient input.jpg output.jpg
```

However, for this image, that does not seem to be the case. There is no orientation field in the meta data.

Comment: Also, this type of picture is usually taken with the check flat on the table, and the camera pointing straight down. The camera orientation is meaningless then.